I am trying to read SPD under MS DOS but I am failing
My 16 bit DOS application uses this code to read SPD via SMBUS but it fails.
I am expecting to read the contents of SPD EEPROM from MS DOS.
How can I read the RAM SPD EEPROM from MS DOS?
Code of the 16 bit application:
bool WaitReady(WORD base)
{
    BYTE STATUS;
    do{
        __asm
        {
            mov dx, base
            in al, dx
            mov [STATUS], al
        }
        }while((STATUS&0x01)!=0);
    return true;
}

void outportb(uint16_t port, uint8_t value)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov dx, [port]
        mov al, [value]
        out dx, al
    }
}

void ReadSPD(WORD base,BYTE offset,BYTE DEVID, BYTE DATA[1])
{
        //output  Base+00 Clear Flags
    outportb(base, 0x1E);
    //output  Base+04,  (DeviceID+1)
    outportb(base+0x04, DEVID+1);
    //out  Base+03,  offset
    outportb(base+0x03, offset);
    //out  Base+02,  48H
    outportb(base+0x02, 0x48);
    //wait  20ms
    __asm
    {
        mov dx, 20000
        xor cx, cx
        mov ah, 86h
        int 15h
    }
    //wait  smbus  ready
    if(WaitReady(base))
    {//input  base+05
        __asm
        {
            mov dx, base
            add dx, 5
            in al, dx
            mov [DATA], al
        }
    }
}

uint16_t SMBUSPORT;

void main()
{
         __asm
        {
           mov eax, 0x8000FB20 ;SMBUS DEVICE
           mov dx, 0xCF8
           out dx, eax
           mov dx, 0xCFC
           in ax, dx
           and ax, 0xFFF0
           mov [SMBUSPORT], ax
        }
        BYTE value[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        ReadSPD(SMBUSPORT, i, 0xA0, value);
        print("%X", value);
    }
}


I expect my program to print the contents of the first SPD EEPROM of DIMM
but all I get is garbage data.
What is wrong with my code?

mov [DATA], al might not be doing what you want. It could be writing to the argument. Maybe you are missing a level of indirection. Anyway, for a single  byte just use a return value.

I tried returning the value but I am still getting garbage data, How can I communicate with the SMBUS in 16 bit real mode?

eax doesn't look very 16-bit to me.

There seem to be a few inconsistencies in your code when accessing arguments. (e.g.) port in outportb vs. base in WaitReady. The mov insts should be the same level of indirection. Also, what compiler/assembler/linker are you using?

@BoP you can use eax in 16 bit real mode if you actually have a 32 bit CPU.

eax is used  in order to send SMBUS DEVICE PCI ADDRESS to port 0xCF8 because is 32 bit address and then reading from port 0xCFC should return SMBUS PORT value, also i am using OpenWatcom compiler

Does Watcom inline asm save registers for you the way MSVC does?  Your asm only uses call-clobbered ("volatile") registers if the calling convention is like 32-bit conventions, but wouldn't hurt to look at disassembly to see if the compiler is expecting one of EAX, ECX or EDX to have the same value after your instructions which modify it.

Yes Watcom saves inline asm registers the same way MSVC does, I only need 32 bit eax in order to get the 16 bit SMBUS port value and send commands to it using 8 bit al register, the code returns the SMBUS port value but sending commands to that port does nothing, I don't understand why? the same code works on windows 32 bit exe using kernel driver

I don't understand why sending commands to SMBUS from 16 bit code doesn't works https://www.smbus.org/
